# TCP receiver-loop

Tags: java, tcpclient, file-transfer

I beg for help
On the client side to receive files. Variable input record file name. Inputstream "is" and FileOutputStream "bos" are responsible for saving the file. The first file is delivered but the other received file occurs java.lang.NullPointerException in variable name.How do I treat this loop for create a file, that the input variable will contain the next new name of the file and stream "is" will contain new data? File poison.pill signals the end of transmission.

```
public class Receiver implements Runnable {


    private int port;

    public Receiver(int port) {

        this.port = port;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            InetAddress adresa = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

            System.out.println("klient sa pripaja na adresu: " + adresa);
            socket = new Socket(adresa, this.port);

            System.out.println("socket = " + socket);
            while (true) {
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String name = input.readLine();
            /// while (???????) {}



                if (name.equals("poison.pill")) {// null pointer exception

                    bos.close();
                    socket.close();
                    break;
                }

                int filesize = 1400;

                int bytesRead;
                byte[] bytearray = new byte[filesize];
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(name);
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytearray)) != -1) {
                    bos.write(bytearray, 0, bytesRead);
                    bos.flush();
                }

            }



        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

In case of misunderstanding i explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand you, but what do you want ? look to your code and you can see

1. Read line from inputStream -> fileName `input.readLine()`
2. Read **all!!!!** data from input stream `while ((bytesRead =
   is.read(bytearray)) != -1) {` -1 means stream is empty
3. After it your loop goes to star and tried to read line (p1), yes
   stream is empty (p2) and you have `NullPointer`.

Solution, wait untill some data is arrived to stream ...

Comment: That's what I want.Unfortunately I do not know. Therefore, the / / / while (????) {...} How can I wait for the data?